# IBM Cloud: How to obtain Activity Tracker / Log Analysis service key via API or Terraform?

Tags: ibm-cloud, terraform-provider-ibm, logdna

I am using both the Activity Tracker and Log Analysis services on IBM Cloud, both are based on LogDNA. In order to export logs, e.g., to [search them via my scripts](https://blog.4loeser.net/2019/08/track-it-from-command-line-search-audit.html), it requires a service key, not the IBM Cloud IAM API key. How can I obtain that key without going through the UI and the LogDNA dashboard? Ideally this is through a REST API or integrated with the Terraform provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service key for Activity Tracker / Log Analysis now seems to be included in the IBM Cloud resource key information. A resource key can be created and existing keys obtained via the [Resource Controller API](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/resource-controller/resource-controller).

This retrieves an existing resource key, including the LogDNA service key:

```
curl -X GET  \
https://resource-controller.cloud.ibm.com/v2/resource_keys/000-my-resource-key-id-0000 \
 -H "Authorization: $TOKEN"
```

Thus, the service key can also be created or retrieved using the [IBM Cloud Terraform provider and its Resource Management functions](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/IBM-Cloud/ibm/latest/docs/resources/resource_key).

```
data "ibm_resource_instance" "AT_instance" {
    name ="ActivityTracker-Henrik-Dallas"
    service="logdnaat"
}

data "ibm_resource_key" "AT_rk" {
    resource_instance_id=data.ibm_resource_instance.AT_instance.id
    name="TESTkey_Dallas"
}
```

The returned data for **AT_rk** has an **attributes** property with **credentials**. It includes **service_key** and **ingestion_key**.